# The circle for proportional editing shows up around the cursor instead of the vertices I'm selecting. Any ideas as to what could be happening?

Tags: scale, 3d-cursor, proportional-editing

So something happened to the file I'm working on where the circle for proportional editing is snapped to the cursor rather than the selection. It's only specific to this file as well and I'm not familiar enough to know if I accidentally hit some key to make this happen. Does anyone know of a possible accident on my part or is there something wrong with the file itself?

[image: The circle snapping to the cursor instead of the vertices that is selected]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've chosen the 3D cursor as *Transform Pivot Point*, so you probably need to choose another option like *Median Point*:

[image]